# Make an alert with a variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to configure a button that pops up an alert that says who has been getting into the text box. Here is my code:

```
function ok() {
    var code = document.getElementById(code);
    var number = document.getElementById(number);
    var date = document.getElementById(date);
    var activation = document.getElementById(activation)
    if ( activation.value == "1234") {
       alert("good code")
    } else if (activation.value != "1234") {
        alert("bad code");
    }
}
```

Why does not it work? Cordially.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You probably meant to pass the strings `"code"`, `"number"`, etc. as ids to `document.getElementById` and not the empty variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes in all your document.getElementById code this will alert good or bad based on what the user inputs.

```js
function ok(){
  //var code = document.getElementById(code);
  // var number = document.getElementById(number);
  //var date = document.getElementById(date);
  var activation = document.getElementById('activation')
  if (activation.value == "1234") {
alert("good code")
  } else if (activation.innerHTML != "1234") {
alert("bad code");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="activation" type="text">
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="ok()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use variables before they're declared. You probably want to use strings in the function calls.

In lieu of having your DOM in front of me, this is what I expect you're trying to do.

```
// find the element with id="number"
var number = document.getElementById("number");
```